Alternatives to Microsoft Graph API Execute Excel Script
I am working with Microsoft Graph API and have run into something of a roadblock.
We have an Excel Online workbook in SharePoint. This workbook is linked from a different workbook. Within this linked workbook, there is a script which just essentially refreshes the link and updates the data in the workbook.
I was hoping to use Graph API to accomplish, but in all of my reading and research and scouring various user groups and posts, it looks as though the methods that used to exist for this (i.e., getScripts, executeScripts) no longer exist. Whenever I try to execute them based on the existing documentation I've found, I get a "no segment found" error.
So the question being: were script methods deprecated in Graph API? If not, where is documentation on how to implement the API call? If they are indeed DOA, what other methods - besides Power Automate - have people used to refresh links/connections in Excel Online?
I've looked everywhere and all signs I've found point to Power Automate being the only option.
Thanks for any insight.

You can use Office JS API for excel sheet manipulation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview?view=common-js-preview

Thank you for the input, but I'm still a little confused. I'm not that proficient with JavaScript, so forgive me!
There is an Excel.LinkedWorkbookCollection which has a method refreshall(). I've been looking for example but can't seem to find one.
Let's say I have an Excel workbook that is linked to a master Excel sheet in SharePoint. So how would you craft the javascript code to:
1.) connect to the SharePoint instance
2.) Connect to the linked workbook
3.) Execute either a refresh all links or execute a specific script in the sheet to refresh the link
Again, not a lot of JS here! Thx

And from what I've read, your solution is for building add-ins to Office hosted products. If I just want to refresh a workbook link via an endpoint and a web activity in Data FActory, I don't bellieve this is the ticket, but correct me if I'm wrong.
Thakns!
